Can I spin up storybook in my salesforce repo and its existing lwc components?
I have limited knowledge and experience in working with storybook and salesforce. Searched links or referenes online but couldn't find anything specific about getting storybook up with existing salesforce repo and its lwc components.
My question to the community is whether is this doable and if so, what I need to do to make it work?
So far I was able to get something up and running independently following setup from https://github.com/reiniergs/lwc-storybooks-poc and I think the repo is using something lwc-webpack-plugin.
  "dependencies": {
    "@salesforce-ux/design-system": "2.11.0-beta.1",
    "classnames": "^2.2.6",
    "lwc-webpack-plugin": "^0.3.0"
  },

Below screenshot of my salesforce structure. Namespace

Code snippet for the .js file.
import { LightningElement, api, wire } from "lwc";

export default class WsTextareaLwc extends LightningElement {
.
.
.

The issue in my storybook is that storybook could not find module "lightning-textarea".
Existing code snippet in .html file.
<template>
        <lightning-textarea
          label={label}
          onblur={handleOnBlur}
          onchange={onchangeMethod}
          class={labelofTextArea}
          onkeyup={wordCount}
          style=" padding-top: 30px; padding-left: 20px; padding-right: 20px;"
        ></lightning-textarea>
        {label}
</template>

I had to remove the <lightning-textarea> just to make storybook run. I can't remove it because that is part of the salesforce lightning code/element.
Any help is much appreciated.
